# Http to Https redirection in Heroku or how to install react-https-redirect?

Tags: reactjs, ssl, heroku, https

I have a React app in Heroku. https://tiket.hu and http://tiket.hu

`Https` works ok, but not `http`. I would deal only with `https`. Is it possible to automatically change http to https?

---

The thing I tried is to install `react-https-redirect`.

First I installed `typescript`, then `react-https-redirect`.

I only installed `type-script` because it was required by `react-https-redirect`.

```
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3
.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

But `react-https-redirect` does not work. What is the norma procedure in this case? I have run `npm audit`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply below code in Server/index.js

```
var sslRedirect = require(‘heroku-ssl-redirect’);
const app = express();
app.use(sslRedirect());
```

Refer this [post in medium](https://medium.com/@seunghunsunmoonlee/how-to-enforce-https-redirect-http-to-https-on-heroku-deployed-apps-a87a653ba61e)